# Get parent iframe element by an element located within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Assuming you have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="..">
       <!-- The following would be the content of the iframe -->
       <html><head></head><body>
           <span>I'm the node</span>
       </body></html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And you have a variable `iframeNode` containing the `<span>` element within that iframe. Your script context is the parent window.

How would you get the parent iframe element:

```
<iframe src="..."></iframe>
```

by this node?

In theory:

```
var iframe = iframeNode.myParentIframeElementInTheParentScope;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only reference to the `iframe` is a `span` in that `iframe` (= `iframeNode`), then

`var iframe = iframeNode.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement;`

will refer to the iframe element in the parent window.